# android: custom ImageView onDraw method not drawing properly on y-axis

Tags: java, android, imageview, scaling

I am trying to track a person's location within a building, using a map. When the user starts, they should be at the doorway to the room 307, but when I draw them (indicated by the green circle), they are correctly placed on the x-axis, but too high up on the y-axis. Is there an error in my scaling code or positioning? The user starts at x=163,y=414. Does canvas.getHeight() not return the value I went when using `fillStart`?

I have written the following onDraw method for my MyImageView, the MainActivity tracks where the user is currently with x,y coordinates:

```
public class MyImageView extends ImageView {
    private Paint p = new Paint(Paint.ANTI_ALIAS_FLAG);
    private float scaleX, scaleY;
    private MainActivity ma;

    @Override
    protected void onDraw(Canvas canvas) {
        super.onDraw(canvas);
        float x = ma.getX();
        float y = ma.getY();
        Drawable d = getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.ist_level_3);
        scaleX = (float)  d.getIntrinsicWidth() /canvas.getWidth();
        scaleY = (float)  d.getIntrinsicHeight()/canvas.getHeight() ;
        p.setARGB(255, 0, 255, 20);
        p.setStyle(Style.FILL);

        canvas.drawCircle( (x * scaleX), (y * scaleY), 10, p);
        Log.i("MyImageView", String.format(
                "xy %.2f,%.2f Drawing %.2f,%.2f Scales %.2f, %.2f", x, y,
                (x * scaleX), (y * scaleY), scaleX, scaleY));


    }
```

I have used it in my layout like this:

```
  <com.jonathanmackenzie.indoortracking.MyImageView
        android:id="@+id/istMap"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:scaleType="fitStart"
        android:src="@drawable/ist_level_3" 
        android:onClick="resetLocation" />
```

The map is is showing up correctly like this:

[image]

Comment: Hi Jonno, I have one question about this indoor implementation.How you are managing this circle, suppose this current Image if I scroll from lelt to right than how you will manage this user current location because its always present on canvas means if you scroll this image in right side current user position some where on left side then how you will handle this because this user location always present on canvas?

Comment: In the application code, you need to store the user's current location as an x,y coordinate. Then when they move this variable is updated and their position redrawn in the `onDraw` method of a class that extends `ImageView`

Comment: Hi Jonno, in my app i can scroll my map from left to right or right to left.So the solution was provided by you is not work in my case because when user scroll map from left to right or right to left user location will be visible even if user is not reached at this position because by using onDraw API I can draw circle but is laways be visible either user reached or not onto that point (if map image is too large). by using onDraw API you can't paste you user location on map image.

Comment: Thanks for your valuable time.

Answer (score 1):

Have you looked at the `setWillNotDraw(boolean)` function on the `ImageView` object? It helped me out maybe this also is your problem?

For the documentation:

http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.html#setWillNotDraw(boolean)

Answer (score 0):

Obvious. You forgot that Y=0 is at the top of the screen. While your entrance is most likely provided in the standard coordinate system with 0 at the bottom.